# fabricjs - Apply SVG inline-style to objects

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using `loadSVGfromURL` to fill a canvas with [this SVG](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/balibart-s3/SVGMockups2/59f32980b5d8493ef7f29904/front/Layer.svg)

As you can see in the link, I got some Heather effect on my shirt, along with some shadows. Plus, my SVG style applies a `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` to my paths.

Unfortunately, once rendered in my canvas, it seems like the paths CSS is not taken into account : 
[image: same image, but no heather nor shadows]

How can I make sure that this style is applied ?

Comment: You can used as a image and use `fabric.Image.fromURL`

Comment: @MariusTurcu What do you mean ? Using it on my SVG URL will only return the first object of my SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an exemple. Basically you need to map mix-blend-mode to globalCompositeOperation

```js
var site_url = 'http://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/balibart-s3/SVGMockups2/59f32980b5d8493ef7f29904/front/Layer.svg';



canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(site_url, function(objects) {

  var group = new fabric.Group(objects, {
    left: 165,
    top: 100,
    
  });
  canvas.add(group);
  group._objects[3].globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
  group._objects[2].globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
  group._objects[4].globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
  group._objects[5].globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
  group._objects[6].globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
 /*for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
 canvas.add(objects[i]);
 }
 canvas.getObjects()[5].globalCompositeOperation='multiply';*/
 // canvas.add(objects);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="900" height="900"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok ! Will I still be able to use fabric parsing methods ? The goal is to dynamically change some of the SVG elements. `LoadSVGFromURL` allows it with the callback / reviver

Comment: No. It will be work as a png image. Another ideea that cross my mind is to make a get request. Somethig like https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/balibart-s3/SVGMockups2/59f32980b5d8493ef7f29904/front/Layer.php?fill=#cc&blend=blur. There you get this parameters and use for changing some svg parameters

Comment: I guest you want this svg to be only a placeholder. No need to parse it and used as `fabric.Group` because the content of a svg is pretty complex and unpredictable and you don't really know what exactly fabric.js supports.

Comment: Do you know if this `mix-blend-mode` thing is handled by fabric, without using filters ?

Comment: Here is an example:http://jsfiddle.net/heL4ymnx/1/ .Basically you need to map `mix-blend-mode` to  `globalCompositeOperation`.

Comment: Please validate the answer if it helped you